# Windows 8 XAML C# implement Page_Error?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a base page for my Windows 8 application. I am trying to create a page Error method so that any error that occur in the entire application can be bubbled up to base page and handled there. I have been following same approach in ASP.Net application. But I am unable to find any Page error method or some way to handle exception on base page for entire application. How can I achieve this using C#, XAML in Windows 8 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRT development is nothing like ASP.Net.

You're looking for the [`Application.UnhandledException` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: Actually this for Unhandled Expection only. I want to create some base class where I can handle any exception that is popped up from any child class.